# Nest.js And Restful CRUD, Why Isn't This Posting?

Tags: nestjs

I have an Angular service that has successfully posted to Firebase and to Postgres through a PHP middleware called DreamFactory.  The Angular app works.  The problem is in the Nestjs controller @Post() or service add() below.  I want to post a json object called recordData.  I'm getting an empty object instead of my json data, which is correct in the Angular service.  Server console.log results:

```
recordData in controller:  {}
req:  {}
recordData in service:  {}
```

The Angular CORS proxy server is working in the Angular dev terminal:

```
[HPM] POST /api/members -> http://localhost:3000
```

Angular is using the dev server port 4200, Nestjs is on 3000.  The typical development setup.

What's wrong?  The payload isn't arriving in the controller.  I'm new to server coding.

Angular http.service.ts:

```
  private api = '/api/';
  ...
  public addRecord(dbTable: string, recordData):  Observable<any> {
    return this.http
      .post(`${this.api}${dbTable}`, recordData);  
  // For this example I'm posting to localhost:3000/api/members db table.
  }
```

My members Nest controller. @Get works, @Post doesn't.

```
@Controller('api/members')  // /members route
export class MembersController {
  constructor(private readonly membersService: MembersService) {}

  @Get()
  async findAll(): Promise<Members[]> {
    return await this.membersService.findAll();
  }


  @Post()
  async addItem(@Req() req, @Body() recordData: AddMemberDto) {
    console.log('recordData in controller: ', recordData);
    console.log('req: ', req.body);
    const result: Members = await this.membersService.addItem(recordData);
    if (!result)
      throw new HttpException('Error adding new Member', HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);

    return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There were several problems, some of which I eventually fixed in the edits above.  However, the main problem was I needed header info as such.  While I had these for other backends they didn't seem to be required for Nestjs.  Wrong idea.  This is my Angular http.service setup.

```
  private headers = new HttpHeaders()
    .set('content-type', 'application/json')
    .set('observe', 'response');

  public addRecord(dbTable: string, recordData):  Observable<any> {
    return this.http
      .post(`${this.api}${dbTable}`, recordData, {headers: this.headers});
  }
```

I also want to note that many implementations of Nestjs use a dto type for the data param, so recordData: AddMemberDto  in the Nestjs controller.  I removed it and it works fine.